# I'm getting weird or encrypted Json format from a server

Tags: json, http, http-post

I'm doing an HTTP request to a server (not mine) but I'm getting some weird json data, as shown in the picture.
I don't know if this is some kind of encryption or something.
[image]

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded data. (The `\/` sequence should be `/`)

Comment: Is there anything I can do to decrypt it?

Comment: base64 decode it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/247261#247261